Appscript (GoogleSheet) sheet.getrange doesnt work
so I'm stuck with a script that I've created, in this script the aim is to automate data from sheets to docs. My script as a whole has been running smoothly but there is 1 function that has an error where I want to put the docs link that has been created into column F in my sheets.
You can access my sheets and docs through here : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1lqkZBS89MK2YDUjaFg4FJh7YD0O6Lcma?usp=sharing
if u can't access the script then I put it here
function createNewGoogleDocs() {
  const googleDocTemplate = DriveApp.getFileById('193ukX8NfW64_hJNPzBabFa4FrCioMj2MNkyvSx1AvNQ'); // Template File ID
  const destinationFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1lqkZBS89MK2YDUjaFg4FJh7YD0O6Lcma'); // Destination Folder ID
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Data'); // Data Sheet Name
  const rows = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  // Skip header row
  const data = rows.slice(1);

  // Group data by PT
  const groupedData = data.reduce((groups, row) => {
    const pt = row[1]; // "PT" column (Column B)
    if (!groups[pt]) {
      groups[pt] = [];
    }
    groups[pt].push(row);
    return groups;
  }, {});

  // Iterate over each PT group
  Object.entries(groupedData).forEach(([pt, group], groupIndex) => {
    try {
      const copy = googleDocTemplate.makeCopy(`Invoice - ${pt}`, destinationFolder);
      const doc = DocumentApp.openById(copy.getId());
      const body = doc.getBody();

      // Replace general placeholders using the first entry in the group
      const firstEntry = group[0];
      body.replaceText('{{Tanggal}}', firstEntry[0]); // Column A
      body.replaceText('{{PT}}', firstEntry[1]); // Column B
      body.replaceText('{{Alamat PT}}', firstEntry[2]); // Column C

      // Target the first table in the document
      const tables = body.getTables();
      const firstTable = tables[0]; // Using the first table

      // Clear any existing rows except the header row and the template row
      const rowCount = firstTable.getNumRows();
      for (let i = rowCount - 1; i > 1; i--) {
        firstTable.removeRow(i); // Remove all rows except the first two (header and template)
      }

      // Insert new rows below the header row
      group.forEach((row, index) => {
        const newRow = firstTable.appendTableRow(); // Create a new row
        newRow.appendTableCell(String(index + 1)); // NO column
        newRow.appendTableCell(row[3]); // AJU NO column (Column D)
        newRow.appendTableCell(row[4]); // Placeholder for TANGGAL SURAT JALAN
        newRow.appendTableCell(row[6]); // Placeholder for NO BL / NO DO
        newRow.appendTableCell(row[7]); // NO CONTAINER column (Column E)
        newRow.appendTableCell(row[8]); // Placeholder for PARTY TRUCKING
        newRow.appendTableCell(row[9]); // Placeholder for PPN
        newRow.appendTableCell(row[10]); // Placeholder for TOTAL INV
        newRow.appendTableCell(row[11]); // Placeholder for TOTAL INV
        newRow.appendTableCell(row[12]); // Placeholder for TOTAL INV
      });

      // Optionally, remove the last row if it is an unnecessary template row
      firstTable.removeRow(rowCount - 1);

      doc.saveAndClose();
      const url = doc.getUrl();
      sheet.getRange(index + 1, 6).setValue(url)
      
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.log(`Error processing group for PT: ${pt}: ${error}`);
    }
  });
}


From what I understand, the issue that you're experiencing right now is that the script doesn't populate all the links for the documents created in column F. Would that be correct?

yes that is correct, The document link that has been created and saved on the drive should go into column F

New questions should not be included an an existing question, they should be posted as a new question.

When the script is tested in the example spreadsheet you provided, the Error processing group for PT: rest2: Exception: Child index (4) must be less than the number of child elements (4). shows up, which is what I assume you meant by the 1 function that has an error where I want to put the docs link that has been created into column F in my sheets. statement in the question.
Upon reviewing the code, the cause of the error is
firstTable.removeRow(rowCount - 1);

Removing that from the script should give something like this:


I did not modify the code to generate a separate link for row 3 because the script uses Array.prototype.reduce() to combine all CTH and res2 on the generated Google Document.

